# Entity attributes not listed when exporting products magento2!

Tags: products, export, magento-2.1.8

I am exporting products but entity attributes list not appearing on the page.

When I check in response, it is showing script but not response.

```
<script>
require([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function(){
    if (window['export_filter_gridJsObject'] != undefined) {
        export_filter_gridJsObject.resetFilter = function () {
            return varienGrid.prototype.resetFilter.call(this, varienExport.modifyFilterGrid);
        };
        export_filter_gridJsObject.doFilter = function () {
            return varienGrid.prototype.doFilter.call(this, varienExport.modifyFilterGrid);
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the system product attributes or custom attributes?If its custom attribute you need check for some setting to display them in the list.

Comment: about system product attributes.

Comment: @VinodKumar found any solution? i am facing same issue